# Show that the equation $\sin x = 1 − x^2$ has at least one solution.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a university student taking a real analysis course and I've been asked the question above. I've worked ahead on the term problem sheet so I'm in territory my lecture notes haven't covered, so all I can do is make some entry level observations. If anyone knows the formal and rigorous way to answer this question please let me know!

Naturally the first thing I do is abuse Wolfram-Alpha. There appear to be two solutions that are the roots of $x^2 + \sin x -1 $ occurring near at $x \approx -1.40962 $ and $x \approx 0.636733$

This idea of roots occurring "near" something sounds new to me and is maybe the link I could be missing.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you learnt about the intermediate value theorem? Apply it to the function $f(x) = \sin x - 1 + x^2$ (note that  $x$ is a solution to your equation if and only if $f(x) = 0$).

Comment: $F(x):=1-x^2-\sin x$, continuos function. $F(0)=1>0$; $F(-2)<0$; IVT, there is a $c \in (-2,0)$ with $F(c)=0$.

Comment: IMHO, the "near" notation is only to specify which exactly root is meant if it can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions or maybe if explicit expression is quite long

Answer (score 6):

$\sin(0)=0$ while $1-0=1$ .. that is, $\sin(x)<1-x^2$ at $x=0$

Then $sin(\pi)=0$, but $1-\pi^2 <0$ That is, $sin(x)>1-x^2$ at $x=\pi$

Since $sin(x)$ and $1-x^2$ are continuous, then by the Intermediate Value Theorem, they must cross somewhere between $(0,\pi)$

Answer (score 0):

Draw the graphs, i.e draw y=sin(x) and y=1-x^2. If you are not expected to find the values of x for the above equation, you are good to go.
y=1-x^2 is a simple parabola and, being a uni student you must be familiar with y=sin(x).
hope that helped :")